# Limit of $\frac{x^a-a^x}{a^x-a^a}$

Tags: limits, analysis, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

Limit of $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{x^a-a^x}{a^x-a^a},$$ where $$a\in (0,\infty), a\neq1.$$
I know to use L'Hopital, but i am confused with the requirments of $a$.

Comment: What's confusing about letting $a$ be any positive number different from $1$?

Comment: Find a duplicate post here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2633321/existence-of-the-following-limit searched by [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim%5Cfrac%7Bx%5Ea-a%5Ex%7D%7Ba%5Ex-a%5Ea%7D%24&p=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that you are computing the limit of,
$$f(x)=\frac{x^a-a^x}{a^x-a^a}\,,$$
is not defined for either $a=1$ or $a=0$, as the denominator would be zero for all $x$. Also, we need $a\geq0$, because $a<0$ implies that $a^a$ is a complex number. Those are the reason of the conditions on $a$:
$$ a\geq0 \wedge (a\notin\{0,1\}) \Rightarrow a\in(0,\infty)\wedge a\neq1.$$

To compute the limit, use L'Hopital knowing that $\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}a^x = a^x\log(a)$ and $\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}x^a = ax^{a-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

The way without L'Hospital:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{x^a-a^x}{a^x-a^a}=-1+\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{x^a-a^a}{a^x-a^a}=-1+\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{\frac{x^a-a^a}{x-a}}{\frac{a^x-a^a}{x-a}}=$$
$$=-1+\frac{(x^a)'_{x=a}}{(a^x)'_{x=a}}=-1+\frac{a\cdot a^{a-1}}{a^a\ln{a}}=-1+\frac{1}{\ln{a}}.$$